# PHP regex help please

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I will have a table an and each table there might be 1 - 6 references to votes what I need is a regex to get the vote amount, My table looks something like:

```
<tbody><tr>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <div class="tp">
 10 VOTES
 </div>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <div class="tp">
 9 VOTES
 </div>
 </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: you can't parse html properly using a regular expression, as html is not a regular language. i highly recommend using an xml parser for this instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you shouldn't try to use a regex to parse HTML, as HTML is not a regular language.

That said, this is a simple enough case, so if you *were* to use a regex here it might look something like this:

```
$table = '<your html here>';

if(preg_match_all('|^\s*(\d+)\sVOTES|m', $table, $matches)) {
    foreach($matches as $match) {
        echo "votes: $match";
    }
}
```

Note that this is highly dependent on the structure of your HTML, and again I really, really do not recommend using a regex for this (use an XML parser!). But you certainly could, as long as you're certain your HTML string will always be consistently formatted.